# Doubts about stopping command line process

Tags: haskell

I found that when I execute

```
a = 1:a
a
```

in command line, I can press Ctrl+c to stop the infinite process.

But Ctrl+c fails to stop the process when I execute

```
length a
```

However, Ctrl+c works well when I execute

```
length [0..]
```

Why does Ctrl+c sometimes fail to stop the process? Is there any ways to stop the process when Ctrl+c is invalid?

Comment: Are you running this in GHCi or compiled with GHC and, if so, have you enabled optimizations?

Comment: In GHCi. What's the difference?

Comment: In this scenario, I'd guess GHC handles C-c only when allocating new memory. If you have a tight loop like the one caused by `length a` which never allocates anything, the thread goes into that loop without any way to escape from it. Probably, it's related to [this bug](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/bugs.html#bugs-in-ghc) and its workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under Windows, there is a bug where, after pressing Ctrl + C, GHCI appears to exit but still seems to run in the background. The only documentation I could find is https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/issues/14150 but I've experienced it myself multiple times using version 9.2.1.when working with infinite data structures like infinite lists [1..].